# ASP.NET MVC 5 How to remove or add attribute in Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC Application View I have
 `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })`

I need to remove the readonly-attribute when an if-statement occurs in my Controller.
How can I, from the Controller, remove the attribute in the View, or add the attribute if I first remove it from the View and then change my if-statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to conditionally add the `readonly` attribute to a textbox.

You may use `ViewData` for that, from your controller assign `ViewData["IsEmailReadOnly"]` to a boolean value

```
if(MyCondition())
    ViewData["IsEmailReadOnly"] = true;
else
    ViewData["IsEmailReadOnly"] = false;
```

And then inside your View:

```
@{
    object textBoxAttrs;
    if((bool) ViewData["IsEmailReadOnly"]) {
        textBoxAttrs = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" };
    }
    else
    {
        textBoxAttrs = new { @class = "form-control" };
    }
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, textBoxAttrs)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm getting the "Property or indexer 'ViewDataDictionary.Is Read Only' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

Comment: I'm sorry, change the property name, `IsReadOnly` could be already implemented in `ViewDataDictionary`. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Not sure if I understand how ViewData works, but no i get the message: 'ViewDataDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'IsEmailReadOnly' and no extension method 'IsEmailReadOnly' accepting a first argument of type 'ViewDataDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I didn't had time to check myself. `ViewData` must be accessed like any dictionary. The answer is not corrected.